# Time varying delay differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, simulation

I would like to know if it is possible in Mathematica to simulate a differential equation with varying delay for example the logistic equation:
 $$x'(t)=x(t)(1-x(t-\tau(t)))$$
where for example $\tau(t)=\sin^2(t)$.
It is mentioned that the NDSolve command only allows constant delays.

Comment: what is the initial condition?

Comment: I am not aware of any Mathematica function that can solve this ODE, but one probably could be written without too much difficulty.

Comment: Could you transform it into an equation with fixed delay somehow?

Answer (score 10):

As noted in my earlier comment, I am unaware of an existing Mathematica function that can solve the variable delay ODE in the question.  Certainly, `NDSolve` objects, when asked to solve it.  So, here is a somewhat rudimentary function written to solve the ODE.  But, it does work, and quickly.  To begin, here is a problem that `NDSolve` can handle.

```
s = x /. Flatten@NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t - 1.05]), 
    x[t /; t <= 0] == Cos[t]}, x, {t, 0, 20}];
pnds = Plot[s[t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

We now construct a simple function to reproduce this result.  Suppose that we have an ODE,

```
x'[t] == c x[t]
```

Then, a finite difference approximation to it is

```
Flatten@Solve[(xp - xm)/dt == c (xp + xm)/2, xp] // Simplify
(* {xp -> -(((2 + c dt) xm)/(-2 + c dt))} *)
```

Use this as the basis for a solution employing `Nest` with time-step `1/10`.

```
xx = N@Table[Cos[t], {t, -1, 0, 1/10}];
Last /@NestList[(xold = First[#]; Append[Rest[#], Last[#] (2 + (1 - xold)/10)/
    (2 - (1 - xold)/10)]) &, xx, 200];
pnst = ListPlot[%, DataRange -> {0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Superimposing these two curves with `Show[pnst, pnds]` indicates that they are identical to the eye.  Before proceeding, we offer a few observations.

- The time step must be of the form `1/n`, with `n` an integer.
- The number of steps that must be saved for `Nest` to process is `Ceiling[n(tdelay-dt/2)]`.
- The offset, `dt/2` arises from the fact that the finite difference template above is centered at a half-integer time step.

For a delay that varies with time, `t` must be specified in the calculation.  This can be done by using `Fold[..., Table[t, {t, 0, 20, 1/10}]` instead of `Nest[..., 200]`.  For instance, to solve an only slightly variable delay,

```
x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t - 1.05 + Sin[t]^2/10])
```

use

```
Last /@ FoldList[(xold = Interpolation[#1, 1 + 1 (1 - Sin[#2]^2)]; 
    Append[Rest[#1], Last[#1] (2 + (1 - xold)/10)/(2 - (1 - xold)/10)]) &, xx, 
    Table[t, {t, 0, 20, 1/10}]];
pnst = ListPlot[%, DataRange -> {0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

which differs only slightly from  the second plot in this answer, as expected.  For a highly variable delay, for instance,

```
x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t - 1.05 + 9 Sin[t]^2/10])
```

replace `Interpolation[#1, 1 + 1 (1 - Sin[#2]^2)]` by `Interpolation[#1, 1 + 9 (1 - Sin[#2]^2)]` in the previous code block to obtain

[image]

in which the oscillation damps much more rapidly.  By way of a warning, the case `Interpolation[#1, 1 + 10 (1 - Sin[#2]^2)]` produces a curve that is not quite accurate at small `t`, because `xold` is too close to `xm` in the original template.  Incidentally, generalization to values of `dt` not equal to `1/n` should not be difficult.